# How Can avoid replace of quotation marks in Pages

Tags: macos, text, text-editor

Sometimes Pages (and many other program, even text-editor) replace the single quotation mark (') with another quotation mark (‘). I write code and If copy and paste the last quotation mark I get an error.

How can I avoid this replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System preferences > Keyboard -> Text -> Use Smart quotes and dashes

[image]